# Deserialize Object returns null with nested JSON when trying to map it

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

I know this question looks familiar but in my case, it is a bit different.

1. I have consumed an API that returns data in XML format.
2. Took the API response and converted it to JSON format so that I can be able to do the mapping.

My problem,
When I DeserializeObject it always returns null and I am not too sure if this is been caused by the mapping.

**Question**: How can I deserialize nested JSON objects for mapping the fields? Also please guide me if I have to change something in terms of converting XML to JSON

Thanks!

**Converting XML response to JSON**

```
            var result = await client.GetAsync($"url");

            var xml = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(xml);
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);

            //the results hear is null for all the properties
            var des = (AccountLite)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, typeof(AccountLite));
            Console.WriteLine(des);
            Console.ReadLine();
```

**JSON Object**

```
{
"MessageEnvelope": {
    "ListOfAccountLite": {
        "AccountLite": [
            {
                "Id": "",
                "AccountStatus": "",
                "AccountTypeCode": "",
                "CSN": "",
                "Location": "",
                "MasterAccountId": "",
                "Name": ""
            },
            {
                "Id": "",
                "AccountStatus": "",
                "AccountTypeCode": "",
                "CSN": "",
                "Location": "",
                "MasterAccountId": "",
                "Name": ""
            },
            {
                "Id": "",
                "AccountStatus": "",
                "AccountTypeCode": "",
                "CSN": "",
                "Location": "",
                "MasterAccountId": "",
                "Name": ""
            }
        ]
    }   
}
}
```

**C# Generated class based on the JSON object**

```
public partial class Welcome
{
    [JsonProperty("MessageEnvelope")]
    public MessageEnvelope MessageEnvelope { get; set; }
}

public partial class MessageEnvelope
{
    [JsonProperty("ListOfAccountLite")]
    public ListOfAccountLite ListOfAccountLite { get; set; }
}

public partial class ListOfAccountLite
{
    [JsonProperty("AccountLite")]
    public AccountLite[] AccountLite { get; set; }
}

public partial class AccountLite
{
    [JsonProperty("Id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("AccountStatus")]
    public string AccountStatus { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("AccountTypeCode")]
    public string AccountTypeCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("CSN")]
    public string Csn { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Location")]
    public string Location { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("MasterAccountId")]
    public string MasterAccountId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The *real* question is why don't you just deserialize the XML data with `XmlSerializer` to objects instead of going through JSON? What does the XML look like? I suspect it *doesn't* match the JSON objects

Comment: The names of those objects look suspiciously like the names a WCF service would generate. In which case, you already have a WCF proxy generated by the SOAP service's WSDL that produces strongly typed objects. Even if you don't, you can generate the DTOs from the WSDL and XSDs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply deserialize to the root class `Welcome` instead of `AccountLite`.

```
//var des = (AccountLite)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, typeof(AccountLite));

Welcome welcome = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Welcome>(json);
```

Comment: How then do I loop through the root since it got ( Welcome > MessageEnvelope > ListOfAccountLite > AccountLite) 

AccountLite is the one which I start to see the results

Comment: Here's a simple loop: `foreach(AccountLite accountLite in welcome.MessageEnvelope.ListOfAccountLite.AccountLite)`

Comment: one last thing before I let you go.  On AccountLite class there's AccountStatus which shows active accounts. I want to filter and get active accounts only so that the query doesn't take long reading in-active accounts

Comment: foreach (AccountLite accountLite in welcome.SiebelMessageEnvelope.ListOfAccountLite.AccountLite.Where(sd => sd.AccountStatus == "Active"))

Comment: I have done something like that and it seems to be fine